# Divide this expression into three specified parts, each of which is simple to the simplest

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have some long expressions like `exp` which can be divided into three specified part. I want to simplify each part to its simplest one use `FullSimplify`.

The specified parts should be:

1. the first part is `term1 = factor1 * E^(-(t/τe1))`,
2. the second part is `term2 = factor2 * DiracDelta[t]`,
3. the third part is `term3 = factor3`.

Here `factor1`, `factor2`, and `factor3` shold not have `E^(-(t/τe1))` or `DiracDelta[t]`.

The one long expression is like this

```
exp = 1/(16 π (-1 + δ)) (1 + 
    2 (1/(9 η0^2 (λ0 + μ0)^4) E^(-(t/τe1)) μ0^2 (-(3 
λ0 + 2 μ0) (6 η0 (λ0 + μ0) (λ0 +2 μ0) - 
             t μ0^2 (3 λ0 + 2 μ0)) - 
          x (6 η0 λ0 (λ0 + μ0) + 
             t μ0^2 (3 λ0 + 2 μ0))) + ((λ0 + 
            2 μ0) (x + λ0 + 2 μ0) DiracDelta[
           t])/(λ0 + μ0)^2 - 
       3 (-((E^(-(t/τe1)) μ0^2 (3 λ0 + 
                 2 μ0))/(3 η0 (λ0 + μ0)^2)) + ((λ0 + 
               2 μ0) DiracDelta[t])/(λ0 + μ0))))
```

I know firstly I should `Expand` it into some terms, then divide these terms into three part, then use `FullSimplify` to simplify them.

But I don't know how to use `MatchQ` to get these three specified parts.

Please help me!

Thank you very much!

**Edit 2017/05/27**

The `exp` without synatix error is like this:

```
exp=(1 + 2 ((E^(-(
  t/\[Tau]e1)) \[Mu]0^2 ((-3 \[Lambda]0 - 
      2 \[Mu]0) (6 \[Eta]0 (\[Lambda]0 + \[Mu]0) (\[Lambda]0 + 
         2 \[Mu]0) - t \[Mu]0^2 (3 \[Lambda]0 + 2 \[Mu]0)) - 
   x (6 \[Eta]0 \[Lambda]0 (\[Lambda]0 + \[Mu]0) + 
      t \[Mu]0^2 (3 \[Lambda]0 + 2 \[Mu]0))))/(
9 \[Eta]0^2 (\[Lambda]0 + \[Mu]0)^4) + ((\[Lambda]0 + 
   2 \[Mu]0) (x + \[Lambda]0 + 2 \[Mu]0) DiracDelta[
  t])/(\[Lambda]0 + \[Mu]0)^2 - 
3 (-((E^(-(t/\[Tau]e1)) \[Mu]0^2 (3 \[Lambda]0 + 2 \[Mu]0))/(
    3 \[Eta]0 (\[Lambda]0 + \[Mu]0)^2)) + ((\[Lambda]0 + 
      2 \[Mu]0) DiracDelta[
     t])/(\[Lambda]0 + \[Mu]0))))/(16 \[Pi] (-1 + \[Delta]))
```

After using `exp2=Collect[exp, {DiracDelta[t], Exp[-\[Tau]/\[Tau]e1]}, Simplify]`, I get

```
exp2=(E^(-(t/\[Tau]e1)) (9 E^(
 t/\[Tau]e1) \[Eta]0^2 (\[Lambda]0 + \[Mu]0)^4 - 
2 \[Mu]0^2 (x (6 \[Eta]0 \[Lambda]0 (\[Lambda]0 + \[Mu]0) + 
      t \[Mu]0^2 (3 \[Lambda]0 + 2 \[Mu]0)) - (3 \[Lambda]0 + 
      2 \[Mu]0) (t \[Mu]0^2 (3 \[Lambda]0 + 2 \[Mu]0) + 
      3 \[Eta]0 (\[Lambda]0^2 - \[Mu]0^2)))))/( 144 \[Pi] (-1 + \[Delta]) \[Eta]0^2 (\[Lambda]0 + \[Mu]0)^4) + ((x - 
2 \[Lambda]0 - \[Mu]0) (\[Lambda]0 + 2 \[Mu]0) DiracDelta[t])/( 8 \[Pi] (-1 + \[Delta]) (\[Lambda]0 + \[Mu]0)^2)
```

Its return is very close to the answer I want. But `exp2` has two terms, not three. The first term of `exp2` contains `E^(-(t/\[Tau]e1)) (temp1*(E^(t/\[Tau]e1)+temp2)`.

If I try `Collect[Part[%, 1], Exp[-\[Tau]/\[Tau]e1], Simplify]` on the first term, then MMA just return it without change.

Could you help me to get three terms? I have about 50 long expressions like `exp1`, So I need a function to do this work. Thank you!

Comment: Your expression was not posted correctly.  I tried to fix the formatting but there are syntax errors so will not evaluate.  Would you please try again? **never mind, I think bbgodfrey fixed it.**

Comment: Both @Mr.Wizard and I tried to fix the many formatting errors, and I think we got them all.  In any case, use `Collect[exp, {Exp[-(t/τe1)], DiracDelta[t]}, Simplify]`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have edited my question, thank you very much!

Comment: @bbgodfrey I try your code, then I get two terms, not three terms. I try to use `Collect[Part[%,1], Exp[-(t/τe1)], Simplify ]` on the first term to divide it into two, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @tanghe2014  I obtain three terms when applying `Collect` to `exp` in your edit.

Answer (score 3):

T0 make my comment more concrete, use

```
Collect[exp, {Exp[-t/τe1], DiracDelta[t]}, Simplify]
```

to obtain

```
1/(16 π (-1 + δ)) +
(E^(-(t/τe1)) μ0^2 (-x (6 η0 λ0 (λ0 + μ0) + t μ0^2 (3 λ0 + 2 μ0)) + (3 λ0 + 2 μ0) 
    (t μ0^2 (3 λ0 + 2 μ0) + 3 η0 (λ0^2 - μ0^2))))/(72 π (-1 + δ) η0^2 (λ0 + μ0)^4) + 
((x - 2 λ0 - μ0) (λ0 + 2 μ0) DiracDelta[t])/(8 π (-1 + δ) (λ0 + μ0)^2)
```

In general, `Collect` with `Simplify` can be used to gather together and simplify the coefficients of various subexpressions in larger expressions.

Comment: Thanks, `Collect[exp, {Exp[-t/τe1], DiracDelta[t]}, Simplify]`, then get `(1/(144 \[Pi] (-1 + \[Delta]) \[Eta]0^2 (\[Lambda]0 + \[Mu]0)^4))
 E^(-(t/\[Tau]e1)) (9 E^(t/\[Tau]e1) \[Eta]0^2 (\[Lambda]0 + \[Mu]0)^4 + 
    2 \[Mu]0^2 (-x (6 \[Eta]0 \[Lambda]0 (\[Lambda]0 + \[Mu]0) + 
          t \[Mu]0^2 (3 \[Lambda]0 + 2 \[Mu]0)) + (3 \[Lambda]0 + 
          2 \[Mu]0) (3 \[Eta]0 (\[Lambda]0 - \[Mu]0) (\[Lambda]0 + \
\[Mu]0) + t \[Mu]0^2 (3 \[Lambda]0 + 2 \[Mu]0)))) + ((x - 
    2 \[Lambda]0 - \[Mu]0) (\[Lambda]0 + 2 \[Mu]0) DiracDelta[t])/(
 8 \[Pi] (-1 + \[Delta]) (\[Lambda]0 + \[Mu]0)^2)`

Comment: I get two terms not three terms. It is very close to the answer I want. How to get three terms? Thank you!

Comment: @tanghe2014  I cannot obtain the expression in your comment just above.

Comment: Sorry for my post. If add `Expand` on `exp` in your code, It will return what we want.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment, I find this code works well!

```
intoThreeTerms[exp_]:=Collect[
                        exp // Expand,
                        {Exp[t/\[Tau]e1], DiracDelta[t]},
                        FullSimplify];
myexp2=intoThreeTerms[myexp1]
```

Thank your patient comments and some useful hints!